# Magento 2 UPS fees not showing up in the sidebar

Tags: magento2

When I:

1. Add a product to the cart, then
2. click on the Cart icon
3. and select "view & edit cart"
4. and enter zip

the UPS fees don't show up the first time. I need to click ***[something]*** again in order for them to show up in the sidebar.

How can I make them show up the first time?

Comment: I've edited your question to make it easier for other users to understand. I left a little gap where I wasn't sure what you were doing, so could you [edit] that to make it clear please? Also, if I misinterpreted what you were asking feel free to edit it to say what you intended.